# Vue.js Multiple independent routes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

**Description:**

I am building a electron based Vue.js app with a settings icon that is always visible. Once the user clicks this icon, a settings modal will pop-up. This popup contains its own navigation / `router-links`.

**Question:**

Is it possible to only navigate a specific named `router-view` without actually navigating the main `router-view`

E.g. in Angular this would be done using the `outlet` prop:

```
path: 'settings-general',
outlet: 'settingsOutlet',
component: SettingsGeneralComponent
```

But in Vue all I could find was something like the snippet below, which navigates the main `router-view` to nothing

```
path: '/settings-general',
name: 'settings-general',
components: {
  // default: This should just keep the current loaded component
  settingsOutlet: require('@/components/SettingsGeneral').default
}
```

Below is my current Router config:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login-page',
      component: require('@/components/LoginPage').default
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home-page',
      component: require('@/components/HomePage').default
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings-page',
      components: {
        settingsRouter: require('@/components/SettingsPage').default
      }
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should have the related to your markup router config.

Comment: I´ve updated the question with my current router config. I haven´t included it since its not that much code, but anyways..

Comment: Not follow, sorry